# How can I uninstall Fern Wifi Cracker?

Tags: uninstall, aircrack-ng

I installed Fern (with all its dependencies) with the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb
```

And I used this to launch it in a terminal:

```
sudo python '/home/user/Downloads/Fern-Wifi-Cracker/execute.py'
```

Now I want to completely uninstall it.

I have already remove it from the Ubuntu Software Center (along with the `aircracker-ng`) and I have already use the below commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge fern-wifi-cracker
sudo apt-get remove fern-wifi-cracker
```

... But I still have this folder I cannot delete:

```
/home/user/Downloads/Fern-Wifi-Cracker
```

How do I completely uninstall Fern Wifi Cracker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove the remainder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo rm -rf Fern-Wifi-Cracker
```

Make sure to type this as is. You should not get any errors.

Comment: That worked perfectly! But when I try locate fern on the terminal I receive 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fern-wifi-cracker.list   
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fern-wifi-cracker.md5sums    
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fern-wifi-cracker.prerm
  thosedirectoris too.Should delete them and how?

Comment: The `-f` option should be removed; it's dangerous.